# What is responsible of the pop up asking to save "Login Info" in Xamarin apps?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin

I'm currently working on a simple app with a login feature. My question is, as in the title, when testing my app in debug mode, a pop up asks me to whether or not to save login info (username & password) after I edit these info and I didn't write any specific code for this; so this is quite unexpected for me.

What might be causing this behaviour and where can I find some documentation on it?

Answer (score 0):

this is the [Android AutoFill](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/autofill) service - available in 8.0 and higher